# cmake compilation errors on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi, qmake, ninja

I'm trying to build this [project](https://github.com/rgriebl/brickstore) from source and running into errors. I've built and installed all listed dependencies but the build process fails with errors including:

`error: ‘co_await’ cannot be used in a ‘constexpr’ function`
`error: ‘co_return’ cannot be used in a ‘constexpr’ function`

Thing is I know this code builds on other platforms so suspect it something to do with my setup / compiler / error suppression? I have raised [an issue](https://github.com/rgriebl/brickstore/issues/768) but I've been trying to compile for days and feel like there's something simple I'm missing

Any help would be much appreciated